# muxing overhead: unknown Conversion failed! ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, conversion, video-conversion

Why do I get this error and how to fix it?

```
[jalal@goku imageSequence]$ ffmpeg -i video_0.avi -qscale:v 1 keyframes/vid0/img_%%06d.jpg
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video_0.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.42.100
  Duration: 00:04:16.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1818 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc), 2048x2048 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 1813 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, image2, to 'keyframes/vid0/img_%%06d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 2048x2048 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x1668720] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'keyframes/vid0/img_%%06d.jpg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=N/A    
video:563kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
[jalal@goku imageSequence]$
```

Comment: When you see `ffmpeg` commands using `%%` it likely means it was meant for use in a Windows batch file. As far as I know, batch files require the `%` to be escaped with a special character which happens to also be `%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command line for your purposes should be:

```
ffmpeg -i video_0.avi -qscale:v 1 keyframes/vid0/img_%06d.jpg
```

This should successfully create your images with *6 digits* in the output filenames.

The error in your command line being the extra '%' in the output filename section: `img_%%06d.jpg`.

**References:**

- [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) The definitive guide to creating images from media files using FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue while generating thumbnail image from videos, I was getting error message along the lines of "i/o error... muxing overhead unknown: Conversion failded".
After so much trials and errors including the answer above, i found a solution, which is specifying the output format option.

-f mjpeg or using fluent-ffmpeg:
ffmpeg(videoSurce).outputFormat("mjpeg")

This is because the real issue was that, even though ffmpeg does the processing ie generates the thumbnail, it throws the error because the format of the output was not specified and it assumes same as the input.